# SeekBar decimal increment

Tags: java, android-studio, mobile, seekbar

I'm trying to create a seekbar where the user can inform a price from `$0,000 to $10,000`. I already tried to implement the line: `float value = ((float)progress / 10.0);` but android studio keep giving me the error `incompatible types Required: float Found: Double`

here is the code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gas = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gasTextView);
        SeekBar gasSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.gasSeekBar);
        gasSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                float value = ((float)progress / 10.0);
                gas.setText("Gasolina: "+progress);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

        etanol = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etanolTextView);
        SeekBar etanolSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.etanolSeekBar);
        etanolSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                etanol.setText("Etanol: "+progress);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Did my answer work?

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code - ( just remove decimal)

```
    float value = ((float)progress / 10);
```

And there will be no error.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `cast` place is incorrect...

How about

```java
float value = (float)(progress / 10.0);
```